# Calculating price per minute from total cost and minutes duration

Tags: excel, excel-formula, finance

So for an interview process I was given this workbook to complete the questions on, I have no experience with arithmetic and stuff like this in excel tbh so got stumped and just did the data manipulation ones - but for future how would you actually do this?

Ignore the formula in M I thought I could get somewhere dividing the cost by minutes but that's clearly wrong.

[image]

[image]

Comment: looks right to me, although "Pence" per minute would be 100x pounds per minute, right? I think you are showning pounds/minute

Comment: What? surely they're not all 0.02 pounds per minute? - So you're saying I should put amount/minutes*100 as the formula?

Comment: they all look to be approximately that amount.  But multiply first: `cost * 100 / minutes`

Comment: Ooh that looks a little better, cheers for the help!

Comment: @GarrGodfrey so won’t cost / minutes * 100 give the same result as cost * 100 / minutes ??